# React Native - Edit hitslop of clear button in TextInput

Tags: react-native, expo

React Native's [TextInput](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html) has a `clearButtonMode` property which would display a small `x` button on the right of the input area in iOS through which text can be cleared.

I am having issues with the hit slop of that button. I believe it is too small and easy to miss. I have to press multiple times in order to hit the right spot in order to activate it.

Is there a way to customize this clear button => change its hitSlop, color, etc?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, is to wrap your TextInput element with view and Animated.View, so you can add your own Clear Button with TouchableOpacity for example, and select an icon, colors, size, etc.
So, basically, it would be something like this:

```
<Animated.View style={...}>
  <TextInput value={...} style={...} onChangeText={...} />
  <TouchableOpacity>
    {/* HERE GOES YOUR CLEAR BUTTON, FOR EXAMPLE: */}
    <MaterialIcons size={24} color={'black'} name={'close'} />
  </TouchableOpacity>
</Animated.View>
```